# Why are some of my source files being hidden by CLion?

Tags: clion, hidden-files

I'm using CLion 2022.1 to work on a (C++) project. In this project, I have files named `src/foo/build.hpp` and `src/bar/build.hpp`. These files are included from the `main()` translation unit, and are even listed as sources in the CMake `add_executable()` command.

However, for some reason (which I may totally be at fault for), I can't see these files in my CLion project view. They don't even show up as excluded files (which I've made visible). I suspect there might be somewhere I've told CLion to hide anything with the world "build" in it. But - where?

Where could I have possibly made these files invisible?

Answer (score -1):

In the project settings dialog, navigate to the unintuitively-located

<kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>File Types</kbd> > <kbd>Ignored Files and Folders</kbd>

You probably have a filename pattern there such as `build*` to match build directories. Remove it.